# Best way to handle thousands of connections

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, asynchronous

- I have a **fleet of vehicles** (let's say about 5000, a bit less).
- We want those vehicles to send us their **GPS** Position, let's say every 5 seconds.
- So, as a message, we just need a string (which will probably be a **JSON** object with `date, latitude, longitude and vehicleId`).
- As I am a .Net web developer, I didn't work a lot with TCP connections.
- I found examples over the net with **asynchronous server and clients** so I wrote a little program which simulates about 5000 vehicles sending messages every 5 seconds.
- For now, the server crashes very quickly. It seems it stops receiving messages. I need to investigate why today...
- My question is : am I on the good way ? I mean I only listen on 1 port for the 5000 vehicles.
- Would I have better results if I listen on 50 ports, each for 100 vehicles ?
- Do you think there will be a better way to do what I am trying to do ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 5 seconds is a quite short time to get an update that isn;t really going to change much. Check your business case for receiving such a lot of data. You can get away with much more intermittent calls. (I'd say 1 per minute is the minimum required, we used to do 15 minute updates).

For the calls that are receiving a lot of simple data, you'll probably find constructing an object to handle it, and generally construct the plumbing is taking too much time. You should be throttling the incoming data, reading the packets and handling them very quickly before moving on to the next one. A large-scale system handling many of these incoming streams simultaneously is possibly not the best solution for this case. Certainly, having a object handler for each incoming packet and trying to handle all of them simultaneously is a recipe for disaster.

Without more information I can't help more - you need to profile where the resource usage is, whether its in the system setting up too many handlers, or the network or CPU and change the architecture to minimise the impact in those areas.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NodeJS, because this would suit exactly your use case from my perspective. With that you'll be able to handle many more parallel requests than with "standard" synchronous programming techniques.

For example go to http://blog.caustik.com/2012/08/19/node-js-w1m-concurrent-connections/ to see what can be achieved.

Be aware that you also need a database to store the data I guess, and having 1000 inserts/sec will also put a lot of db servers into trouble. You might want to look at something like Redis or MongoDB for scaling.

There are also examples out there on how to use .NET async functionality similar to your requirements: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx I personally can't say anything about it's performance.